# read pdf browser phonegap

Tags: cordova, pdf, external-links

I'd like to read pdf like that with phonegap:

```
window.open('http://www.mysite.com/file.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

but I have a white page
is there a way to read pdf files without download them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I foudn using the google web service to read pdf.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

To add to what tonylefler said, mozillas pdf.js may work on mobile devices within their moblie browsers and lets you view a pdf without downloading it and opening it in a external viewer.